# python - Как модифицировать переменную в процессе одной программы для другой программы?

Tags: python, консоль, global-variables

Есть 3 файла: constants.py, test2.py, test.py 
 
constants.py

```
test_flag = 0
```

test2.py

```
import os,sys,inspect
import constants
import test

print("Запускаю test2.py")
constants.test_flag += 1
print("тест должен быть 1 - ",constants.test_flag)

cmd2 = "python3.7 /home/dlenskyi/Desktop/smart_gear/test.py " + 
str(constants.test_flag)
for s in sys.argv[1:]:
    cmd2 += " " + s

subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "-e", cmd2])
time.sleep(6)
print("Тест должен быть 2 - ", constants.test_flag)
constants.test_flag += 1
print("Тест должен быть 3 - ", constants.test_flag)
exit(0)
```

test.py

```
import constants
import test2

print("Запускаю test.py")
constants.test_flag += 1
print("Тест должен быть 2 - ", constants.test_flag)
time.sleep(5)
exit(0)
```

Первым я запускаю test2.py, в ходе которого инкрементирую переменную test_flag из constants.py, затем открываю test.py в новом консольном окно и передаю перменную test_flag в качестве аргумента. В файле test.py снова модифицирую test.flag, и далее в test2.py модифицирую его снова. Все это сопровождается выводом значения переменной в формате "Ожидание - реальность".

Но в ходе этих модификаций значение переменной из constants.py не сохраняется и не передается модифицированное ее значение между файлами.
Как это можно исправить?

Мой вывод в консоли:

Главная консоль:

Запускаю test2.py

тест должен быть 1 -  1

Тест должен быть 2 -  1

Тест должен быть 3 -  2

Текст в только что создавшейся консоли:

Запускаю test.py

Тест должен быть 2 -  1

Comment: Использовать [mutliprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) вместо subprocess и разделяемую память или очередь для передачи данных между процессами.

Comment: как это можно реализовать в моей задаче? мне нужно сопроводить эти операции вызовом нового консольного окна, чтоб скрипт там отработал, затем окно закрылось, но значение глобальной переменной для главного файла сохранилось

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Все мои действия и моя задача описаны в вопросе, вопрос также сформулирован. Прошу помочь написать команду, которая поможет сохранить значение глобальной переменной между файлами.

Comment: Суть задачи из вопроса непонятна. У файлов нет никаких переменных. Вам нужно межпроцессное взаимодействие, как вам уже указали в первом комментарии. Правда, до сих пор не ясно, зачем.

Comment: Эти два файла были для примера. С межпроцессорным взаимодействием я еще не сталкивался, поэтому и прошу здесь помощи. Если коротко, я пишу бота для автоматизации процесса получения данных от пользователя, который после получения этих данных запускает другую программу в новой консоли. Отсюда и вытекает мой вопрос о модифицировании глобальных переменных таким путем

Comment: Похоже, что никак: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381628/